# Cannot insert the value NULL into column - NHibernate entity with 2 parents

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

{"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'RootID', table 'Legacy.dbo.Middle'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

I have a Root class, Middle class, and 'bottom' class. The root class as "Middle" as children, then Middle has "Bottom" as children. However, in this legacy database with poor design there is also a reference to "Root" from the "Bottom".

root table

```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Root](
    [RootID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RootName] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Root] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RootID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

middle table

```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Middle](
        [MiddleID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [MiddleName] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
        [RootID] [int] NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Middle] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [MiddleID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

bottom table

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Bottom](
        [BottomID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [BottomName] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
        [MiddleID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [RootID] [int] NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Bottom] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [BottomID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

the foreign keys

```
  ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Middle]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Middle_Root] FOREIGN KEY([RootID])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Root] ([RootID])
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Middle] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Middle_Root]

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Bottom]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Bottom_Middle] FOREIGN KEY([MiddleID])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Middle] ([MiddleID])
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Bottom] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Bottom_Middle]
    GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Bottom]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Bottom_Root] FOREIGN KEY([RootID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Root] ([RootID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Bottom] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Bottom_Root]
```

c# entities

```
  public class Root
    {
        public Root()
        {
            Middles = new SortedSet<Middle>();
        }

        public int RootID { get; set; }
        public string RootName { get; set; }
        public ISet<Middle> Middles { get; set; }
    }

    public class Middle
    {
        public Middle()
        {
            Bottoms = new SortedSet<Bottom>();
        }

        public int MiddleID { get; set; }
        public Root Root
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public ISet<Bottom> Bottoms { get; set; }
    }

    public class Bottom
    {
        public int BottomID { get; set; }
        public Root Root { get; set; }
        public Middle Middle { get; set; }
        public string BottomName { get; set; }
    }
```

I am using the following mappings via FluentNHibernate, but I've tried a ton of variations and just cannot get it to work in any way.

```
public class RootMap : IAutoMappingOverride<Root>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Root> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Not.LazyLoad();
        mapping.Id(x => x.RootID);
        mapping.HasMany(x => x.Middles).KeyColumn("RootID").Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan().Inverse();
    }
}

public class MiddleMap : IAutoMappingOverride<Middle>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Middle> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Not.LazyLoad();
        mapping.Id(x => x.MiddleID);
        mapping.References(x => x.Root);
        mapping.HasMany(x => x.Bottoms).KeyColumn("MiddleID").Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
    }
}

public class BottomMap : IAutoMappingOverride<Bottom>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Bottom> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Not.LazyLoad();
        mapping.Id(x => x.BottomID);
        mapping.References(x => x.Root);
        mapping.References(x => x.Middle);
    }
}
```

Comment: would love some time to let people answer this... I think I have a solution using constructors and FACTORY METHOD on the AGGREGATE "Root"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to declare the many valued side of the relation as "inverse". See last paragraph of section 6.4: http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-onetomany

Comment: I tried that, then I get 'cannot insert null value into column RootID on table dbo.Bottom'. I will give you a +1 though because that's the first time anyone has explained the 'Inverse()' part and made sense! :)

Comment: It might be that you need to use "inverse" also on the "HasMany(bottoms)" part. You should also declare .Not.Nullable() on the references.

Comment: @OskarBerggren You were frickin' right, saved me from my torment. 'ppreciate mate.